# how can solve the “SIGKILL” error in UITableView (when built the table view using Storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm the beginner of IOS development. 
I try to use the Storyboard to produced a UITableView, But when I run this App, it appear the "Program received signal: 'the SIGKILL' ".

I built a table using Storyboard (without ARC), but there is a problem during the runtime .
Here given in the code:

---

```
#import "MainTableViewController.h"
@interface MainTableViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myArray;
@end

@implementation MainTableViewController
@synthesize myArray;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
// Custom initialization
    }
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple",@"orange",@"bananas", nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.myArray = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [myArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // 这儿出现异常 Program received signal:  “SIGKILL”
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ }
@end
```

---

[image]

I moving up and down on the screen, and then occurs this runtime error.
I enabled the Zombie function. I found the "myArray" is NSZombie Objects,

And then the debug continue,
and I found another error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" at the same line.
cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
The myArray still is a zombie object.

How do you solve it?
Thank you! !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created `myArray` using the `arrayWithObjects:` method.  This method returns an object that you do not own.  Since you don't own it, the object might be deallocated (turn into a zombie) the next time the program goes through its run loop.  In fact, that is exactly what is happening.

If you want the object to stay around, you have to become an owner of it.  You do that by retaining it.  There are three ways you can retain it.  You can explicitly send it a `retain` message:

```
myArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple",@"orange",@"bananas", nil] retain];
```

or you can use the property setter method:

```
[self setMyArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple",@"orange",@"bananas", nil]];
```

You can use dot-syntax, which uses the property setter method “under the covers”:

```
self.myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple",@"orange",@"bananas", nil];
```

The property setter method (generated by the compiler) automatically retains the object.

You put the reference directly into your instance variable instead of using the setter method.  It is easy to make this mistake.  The compiler can help you catch this mistake if you synthesize your property differently:

```
@synthesize myArray = _myArray;
```

If you do that, the property is stored in an instance variable named `_myArray`, instead of an instance variable named `myArray`.  So you have to explicitly use the `_` in front of the name to access the instance variable directly:

```
// COMPILE-TIME ERROR!
myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple",@"orange",@"bananas", nil];

// Compiles ok
_myArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple",@"orange",@"bananas", nil] retain];

// Also compiles ok
self.myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple",@"orange",@"bananas", nil];
```

If you use the `_` prefix on all of your instance variables, then you know that whenever you are setting something that starts with an `_`, you need to worry about retaining the new value and releasing the old value.

The *third* way you can retain the object, and the best, is to turn on ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) for your project.  Then you don't have to worry about retaining and releasing objects.  The compiler will automatically retain and release the object at the right times, even if you use the instance variable directly.

If you decide *not* to use ARC, then you *need* to study [*Cocoa Core Competencies*: “Memory Management”](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH27-SW1), until you understand the rules.

Comment: This should be the canonical answer for these sorts of questions. Why don't we have canonical answers on SO?

Comment: +1: added this question to favorite questions because of the answer :)